# Not able to build/make a project in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4

I have an `Ionic` project that I am trying to import, compile and then run through emulator using `Android Studio`.

I imported all the files under `<project_name>/platforms/android` folder and opened it under `Android Studio`.

However when I click on the `Make Project` button I see `No installed build tools found. Install the Android build tools version 19.0.1 or higher.` message at the bottom.

I also tried building the project using command prompt and it worked.

Command: **ionic cordova build android**

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 10s
46 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 45 up-to-date
Built the following apk(s):
        C:\Users\nital\Documents\Tech\RESET-CODE-SAMPLES\IONIC-CODE-SAMPLES\ionic-basics\platforms\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk
```

Env Variables:

```
JAVA_HOME=C:\Java\jdk -> Points to JDK 8
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\nital\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
PATH = C:\Users\nital\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools; C:\Users\nital\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools
```

[image]

Am I missing any configuration settings in Android Studio ?

Comment: Could you try to update the SDK to the latest by installing all the build tools in SDK manager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the error, `Android studio` is not able to find `Build tools`. Just update your `SDK Location` of that Project or of your `Android Studio`

Comment: Added `build-tools` folder in the `PATH` and it worked. Thanks !